# Run liquibase under Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, database-schema, liquibase, baseline

How would one start a liquibase schema db check aginst a base line under Tomcat on a schedule? Like how to deploy liquibase under Tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about utilizing `ServletContextListener` and inside it create new object of
[Liquibase](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/Liquibase.java).

something like

```
import java.sql.Connection;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

import liquibase.Liquibase;
import liquibase.database.Database;
import liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory;
import liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection;
import liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor;
import liquibase.resource.CompositeResourceAccessor;
import liquibase.resource.FileSystemResourceAccessor;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;

@WebListener
public class LiquibaseListener implements ServletContextListener {

  @SneakyThrows
  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    final Connection connection = null;
    final Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(connection));
    final Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("changelogpath", new CompositeResourceAccessor(new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), new FileSystemResourceAccessor()), database);
    liquibase.update("");
    
  }
}
```

Or have a look inside [SpringLiquibase](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/integration/spring/SpringLiquibase.java) how this is done for spring framework and you can get inspiration from there.

Comment: Thanks for the info @bilak  In your code, how would i tell it I want JSON output for the results?

Comment: for which results?

Comment: I thought there was only one output and that was to display each checked database table and determine if its the same or to list what was not the same.